# Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am trying to implement **push notification** in **ionic framework v1**.

That is why to start of I am downloading a *blank* template where I am getting the **'statusCode'** error.

```
C:\Users\sif-\Desktop\vConnect_31_5_16>ionic start vConnectPro blank
Creating Ionic app in folder C:\Users\sif-\Desktop\vConnect_31_5_16\vConnectPro
based on blank project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-blank/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Update Config.xml
Initializing cordova project

? ♫ ? ♫  Your Ionic app is ready to go! ? ♫ ? ♫

Make sure to cd into your new app directory:
  cd vConnectPro

To run your app in the browser (great for initial development):
  ionic serve

To run on iOS:
  ionic run ios

To run on Android:
  ionic run android

To test your app on a device easily, try Ionic View:
  http://view.ionic.io

New! Add push notifications, live app updates, and more with Ionic Platform!
  https://apps.ionic.io/signup

C:\Users\sif-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\cli.js:474
      process.stdout.write('Unable to fetch', err, res.statusCode);
                                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\sif-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\l
ib\cli.js:474:55)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\sif-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_
modules\request\request.js:373:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\sif-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\io
nic\node_modules\request\request.js:971:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:256:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

at first I ignored this since the blank app was running fine but after implementing all the necessary

code for push notification I got the error related to **'statusCode'** again. Which is a blocker for me right now.

How should I go about this to solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is must likely the proxy issue

This issue generated when you are behind the proxy

make sure you are using pc or laptop that is directly connected to internet

Comment: I'm also getting this error. Is there a way to work with this behind a proxy? I've already set the npm config set proxy variable, but where should I also set proxy to avoid this error? thanks